# BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' And SearchException: Cannot write into index directory:

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, entitymanagerfactory

I am using Hibernate search with Spring Boot. I am specifying the index location using the following properties in application.properties file.

**application.properties**

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.search.default.directory_provider = filesystem
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.search.default.indexBase = /var/tmp/lucene/indexes/
```

The issue I am running into is that when the application starts up, the index is created in the specified location, but then the load fails with the stack trace below:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.search.exception.SearchException: HSEARCH000103: Unable to initialize IndexManager named 'com.neostencil.model.entities.ExtraInfo'
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1745)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:576)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1083)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:853)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:546)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248)
    at com.neostencil.NSMainApplication.main(NSMainApplication.java:16)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.search.exception.SearchException: HSEARCH000103: Unable to initialize IndexManager named 'com.neostencil.model.entities.ExtraInfo'
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:402)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:377)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1804)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1741)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.search.exception.SearchException: HSEARCH000103: Unable to initialize IndexManager named 'com.neostencil.model.entities.ExtraInfo'
    at org.hibernate.search.indexes.impl.IndexManagerGroupHolder.doCreateIndexManager(IndexManagerGroupHolder.java:198)
    at org.hibernate.search.indexes.impl.IndexManagerGroupHolder.getOrCreateIndexManager(IndexManagerGroupHolder.java:155)
    at org.hibernate.search.indexes.impl.NotShardedEntityIndexBinder.bind(NotShardedEntityIndexBinder.java:34)
    at org.hibernate.search.indexes.impl.IndexManagerGroupHolder.bind(IndexManagerGroupHolder.java:100)
    at org.hibernate.search.indexes.impl.IndexManagerHolder.buildEntityIndexBinding(IndexManagerHolder.java:100)
    at org.hibernate.search.spi.SearchIntegratorBuilder.initDocumentBuilders(SearchIntegratorBuilder.java:428)
    at org.hibernate.search.spi.SearchIntegratorBuilder.createNewFactoryState(SearchIntegratorBuilder.java:244)
    at org.hibernate.search.spi.SearchIntegratorBuilder.buildNewSearchFactory(SearchIntegratorBuilder.java:200)
    at org.hibernate.search.spi.SearchIntegratorBuilder.buildSearchIntegrator(SearchIntegratorBuilder.java:128)
    at org.hibernate.search.hcore.impl.HibernateSearchSessionFactoryObserver.boot(HibernateSearchSessionFactoryObserver.java:127)
    at org.hibernate.search.hcore.impl.HibernateSearchSessionFactoryObserver.sessionFactoryCreated(HibernateSearchSessionFactoryObserver.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryObserverChain.sessionFactoryCreated(SessionFactoryObserverChain.java:35)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:371)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:462)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:938)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:57)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:390)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.search.exception.SearchException: HSEARCH000252: Unable to initialize directory provider org.hibernate.search.store.impl.FSDirectoryProvider for index com.neostencil.model.entities.ExtraInfo
    at org.hibernate.search.store.spi.BaseDirectoryProviderService.initialize(BaseDirectoryProviderService.java:79)
    at org.hibernate.search.store.spi.BaseDirectoryProviderService.create(BaseDirectoryProviderService.java:64)
    at org.hibernate.search.indexes.spi.DirectoryBasedIndexManager.createDirectoryProvider(DirectoryBasedIndexManager.java:229)
    at org.hibernate.search.indexes.spi.DirectoryBasedIndexManager.initialize(DirectoryBasedIndexManager.java:89)
    at org.hibernate.search.indexes.impl.IndexManagerGroupHolder.doCreateIndexManager(IndexManagerGroupHolder.java:195)
    ... 42 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.search.exception.SearchException: Cannot write into index directory: /var/tmp/lucene/indexes/com.neostencil.model.entities.ExtraInfo for index com.neostencil.model.entities.ExtraInfo
    at org.hibernate.search.store.impl.DirectoryProviderHelper.makeSanityCheckedDirectory(DirectoryProviderHelper.java:160)
    at org.hibernate.search.store.spi.DirectoryHelper.getVerifiedIndexPath(DirectoryHelper.java:91)
    at org.hibernate.search.store.impl.FSDirectoryProvider.initialize(FSDirectoryProvider.java:50)
    at org.hibernate.search.store.spi.BaseDirectoryProviderService.initialize(BaseDirectoryProviderService.java:76)
    ... 46 more
```

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>${java.version}</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>${java.version}</maven.compiler.target>
        <hibernate-core.version>5.4.1.Final</hibernate-core.version>
        <hibernate-search.version>5.11.0.Final</hibernate-search.version>
        <psql.version>42.2.5</psql.version>
        <jjwt.version>0.9.1</jjwt.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Greenwich.RELEASE</spring-cloud.version>
        <actuator.version>2.1.2.RELEASE</actuator.version>
        <googleapiservicesdrive.version>v3-rev136-1.25.0</googleapiservicesdrive.version>
        <jaxbapi.version>2.3.1</jaxbapi.version>
        <mysqlconnector.version>5.1.6</mysqlconnector.version>
        <jsoup.version>1.11.3</jsoup.version>
        <jacksoncore.version>2.9.8</jacksoncore.version>
        <specification-with-projections.version>2.0.0</specification-with-projections.version>
        <google-cloud-storage.version>1.61.0</google-cloud-storage.version>
        <google-api-services-sheets.version>v4-rev553-1.25.0</google-api-services-sheets.version>
        <google-api-client.version>1.28.0</google-api-client.version>
        <google-oauth-client-jetty.version>1.28.0</google-oauth-client-jetty.version>
        <gson.version>2.8.5</gson.version>
    </properties>

    <groupId>com.neostencil</groupId>
    <artifactId>NSWebCore</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <name>NS Complete</name>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-jdk14</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.rometools/rome -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.rometools</groupId>
            <artifactId>rome</artifactId>
            <version>1.12.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-api-services-drive</artifactId>
            <version>${googleapiservicesdrive.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-aws</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-ses</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-sns</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>${psql.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>${mysqlconnector.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate-core.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-search-orm -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-search-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate-search.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.opencsv/opencsv -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.opencsv</groupId>
            <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>${jjwt.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype/jackson-datatype-hibernate4 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-hibernate5</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>${jacksoncore.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>th.co.geniustree.springdata.jpa</groupId>
            <artifactId>specification-with-projections</artifactId>
            <version>${specification-with-projections.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.razorpay</groupId>
            <artifactId>razorpay-java</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.keyos</groupId>
            <artifactId>keyos-authxml-signer</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-cloud-storage</artifactId>
            <version>${google-cloud-storage.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.modelmapper</groupId>
            <artifactId>modelmapper</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-api-services-sheets</artifactId>
            <version>${google-api-services-sheets.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.api-client/google-api-client -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-api-client</artifactId>
            <version>${google-api-client.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.oauth-client/google-oauth-client-jetty -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.oauth-client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-oauth-client-jetty</artifactId>
            <version>${google-oauth-client-jetty.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.zwobble.mammoth</groupId>
            <artifactId>mammoth</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.jackson/jackson-core-lgpl -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core-lgpl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.13</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.xml.bind/jaxb-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>${jaxbapi.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-actuator -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
            <version>${actuator.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
            <version>${jsoup.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Google Guava -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>19.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>${gson.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.rometools/rome -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.rometools</groupId>
            <artifactId>rome</artifactId>
            <version>1.12.0</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>

        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <!-- DO NOT set id to "local" because it is reserved by Maven -->
            <id>lib</id>
            <url>file://${project.basedir}/lib</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <build>
        <plugins>

            <!-- Includes the runtime dependencies -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <executable>true</executable>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!--<plugin> <groupId>com.samaxes.maven</groupId> <artifactId>minify-maven-plugin</artifactId> 
                <version>1.7.6</version> <configuration> <skipMerge>true</skipMerge> <jsEngine>CLOSURE</jsEngine> 
                <nosuffix>true</nosuffix> <cssSourceIncludes> <cssSourceInclude>**/*.css</cssSourceInclude> 
                </cssSourceIncludes> <cssSourceExcludes> <cssSourceExclude>**/*.min.css</cssSourceExclude> 
                </cssSourceExcludes> <jsSourceIncludes> <jsSourceInclude>**/*.js</jsSourceInclude> 
                </jsSourceIncludes> <jsSourceExcludes> <jsSourceExclude>**/*.min.js</jsSourceExclude> 
                </jsSourceExcludes> </configuration> <executions> <execution> <id>default-minify-resources</id> 
                <configuration> <webappSourceDir>${basedir}</webappSourceDir> <webappTargetDir>${project.build.directory}</webappTargetDir> 
                <cssSourceDir>src/main/resources</cssSourceDir> <jsSourceDir>src/main/resources</jsSourceDir> 
                <jsTargetDir>classes</jsTargetDir> <cssTargetDir>classes</cssTargetDir> </configuration> 
                <goals> <goal>minify</goal> </goals> </execution> </executions> </plugin> -->
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Please anyone hlep me and correct me.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this may help you!

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.search.default.indexBase = ./var/lucene/indexes
```

Comment: Finally run my project. Thank you so much Rahul.